# Two rows navbar to collapse in right order

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tried lots of exemples from internet, but couldn't get the wished result.

I'm using bootstrap 3+

I need a menu like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                |                                                       Phone  |
|      LOGO      |                                                      Adress  |
|                |                                                Another info  |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Home                                  Page 1  |  Page 2  |  Page 3 |  Page 4  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

To collpase SM- to something like this:

```
+----------------+
| Phone          |
| Adress         |
| Another info   |
|----------------|
|                |
|      LOGO      |
|                |
|----------------|
|      MENU      |
+----------------+
```

Does anybody have a suggestion?
Thanks!

**EDITED**

So far I got this, but the logo is the first thing on SM-
This is the closest I got to what ai Need.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav  navbar-left">
        <li><img src="images/logo.png"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class=" navbar-right col-lg-6 col-md-6 text-right" >
      Adress<br>
      Phone<br>
      Info
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNav">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNav">
        <ul id="navlist" class="nav nav-justified">
          <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Account Management</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Request a Quote</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">MainSite.com</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: We need some code you tried, and what happens and what you'd like to happen. See [mcve].

Comment: Can you please provide your current code?

Comment: I've updated the question =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have create one snippet for you. It may be helpful

```css
.custom-navbar {
  text-align:right;
}
@media (max-width: 768px){
 .custom-navbar {
   text-align:left;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
   <div class=" navbar-right col-lg-6 col-md-6 custom-navbar" >
      Adress<br>
      Phone<br>
      Info
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav  navbar-left">
        <li><img src="images/logo.png"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   
    <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNav">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNav">
        <ul id="navlist" class="nav nav-justified">
          <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Account Management</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Request a Quote</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">MainSite.com</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```